# Golang : Use GCS from GKE

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am looking to enable a Golang application deployed in GKE to use the workload-identity approach to fetch data from the GCS

I have created the workload-identity account  but I am not finding a way to put that in golang gcp sdk to access the gcs objects